# Compatibility Issue with IE10 and IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility, jsp

I have a website that having some applets, which works without any issues in IE6-IE9. But when I tried in IE10 and IE11, it seems to be buggy. All the pages where not loading properly.

After some searches in google, I found adding the following will solve the problem :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

But even after adding this, my problem was not resolved. When I add the above meta tag, IE's document mode was set to IE9 but the browser mode was still IE10/IE11. If I add my site into compatibility mode it works as good as in IE6-IE9. But whenever the machine accessing the site changes, I need to add the site into compatibility mode.

I would like to know whether I can change code from the server side to solve this compatibility issue of my web site.

My web site's server side uses jsp pages containing some applets and servlet. And the site is deployed in Apache Tomcat

Comment: I am hardly an expert in coding Java/JavaScript, but when I managed thousands of web servers and sites, this was a common problem because browsers do not all handle JavaScript the same. When dealing with JavaScript in particular, it is not uncommon to have to test the browser/browser version and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like your attempting to use a band aid rather than addressing the real issue. It would be better to address the issue for future compatibility.

Comment: @bybe Also I am very keen to know what is going wrong when IE is upgraded  from 9 to 11. It was working fine till IE 9.

Comment: Would you mind posting the scripts that are causing issues?

Comment: @ECarterYoung how can we confirm that scripts are culprit in this case..?? It may be because of Applets, may be because of css, may be because of some other issues..how can i find which is really causing the problem..?

Comment: 1. Comment Out the CSS, reload the page.  Does the page behave?  If not, 2. Uncomment the CSS, and Comment the Scripts.  Does the Page Behave.  See also [here regarding the Chakra JIT Compiler](http://betanews.com/2013/11/07/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-is-all-about-performance/) and the [Wiki Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra_(JScript_engine).  In short, there may be a compatibility issue between the new scripting engine and your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the meta tag your put on your pages, MSIE is running in Internet Explorer 9 mode, even if its a newer version.  This usually does the trick with CSS, but other items such as plugins, javascript, and other activex dont really follow the rules.

Your best bet is to fix the site so it works for MSIE10+, which in all liklihood means it will work for chrome, firefox, safari and opera since MSIE10 is actually a really good browser.

Comment: yea you are correct :) I am about to finish rebuilding the site :D